# Identical strings don't seem to be treated as identical for the if statement

Tags: string, if-statement, rust, string-comparison, equality

I am writing a small program to read a list of passwords and search for a password that has been inputted by the user. For some reason, even if I deliberately enter a password that is in the file, it doesn't print that the password is found.
Below is the full code. It just seems whatever I do I cannot compare two strings!

```
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let user_password: String = user_input::get_user_input("Enter password:");

    let file: File = File::open("passwords.txt")?;
    let reader: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line: String = line.unwrap();
        if line == user_password {
            println!("Password file contains {}!", user_password);
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Just before the if statement, I did:

```
println!("{}:{}", line, user_password);
```

and it was identical!

I have tried

```
if line.contains(&user_password)
```

and I have also tried the functional route doing

```
reader.lines().for_each(|line| {
    // the same if statement as above
});
```

EDIT: As requested, here is the code for get_user_input(), apologies for not including that before.

```
use std::io;

pub fn get_user_input(prompt: &str) -> String {
    println!("{}", prompt);

    let mut user_input: String = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_input).expect("Failed to read line");

    user_input
}
```

Comment: How is `get_user_input` implemented?

Comment: There's not enough info to answer the question. However, if I had to take a guess, if you replace the `{}` with `{:?}` in your `println!` you'll see that `user_password` ends in `\n` but `line` doesn't.

Comment: An easy way to debug is by doing something like `if dbg!(line) == dbg!(user_password)`

Comment: Maybe try `line.trim() == user_password.trim()`.

Comment: @justinas apologies for this, I have added it to the original question

Comment: @Aplet123 I have just added .trim().to_string() for the user_password declaration and it now works. Thank you to you and etchesketch for your answers :) is there a way to mark your comment as an answer, because if there is I can't find it haha

Comment: @Dexygen it does thank you! I must not have used the most optimal search terms